# Add nested packages to install requires, setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, dnspython

I'm new to building binaries and am having a problem adding the `dnspython` module. `Dnspython` sometimes includes some modules dynamically using `__import__` and these modules are nested inside other packages. Therefore the `find_packages()` does not find the required package.

In my case I need the `SRV.py` module which is located in `dns/rdtypes/IN/SRV.py` where `dns` is the `dnspython` package.

The following is my current setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['MongoDB.py']
OPTIONS = {
    "includes": [],
}

setup(
     plugin=APP,
     options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
     setup_requires=['py2app'],
     install_requires=['pyobjc', 'pymongo', 'dnspython'],
)
```

Since I need the `SRV.py` file inside `rdtypes` and `IN`, I thought I called a requirement like so: `dnspython.rdtypes.IN` which did not work. I also tried adding it to the packages(`packages=[dnspython, ...]`) which also didn't work.

I have not found anything regarding these nested packages and how to include them, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When i run the setup.py only the files in the root directory(dns) are copied into the plugin, I am using py2app if it is of some importance. But all the subdirectories inside dns are not copied into the plugin

Comment: @J.Paravicini: That sounds like it's more of a py2app issue than a setuptools issue.

Comment: Hmm could be, have had similar issues with another package. Are there other tools to create python plugins?

Comment: `py2app` seems [having problems](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html) with `__import__` and has worarounds for selected modules but not for `dnspython`. Perhaps you have to develop your own recipe.

Comment: Also try include packages recursively, i.e. list all subpackages explicitly: `OPTIONS = {'packages': ['dns', 'dns.rdtypes', 'dns.rdtypes.ANY', 'dns.rdtypes.IN']}`

Comment: I did this except of using packages I used includes. Do you know what the difference is?

Comment: `includes` includes [**modules**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), i.e. separate files `*.py`. `packages` adds [**packages**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), i.e. directories with `__init__.py` and `*.py` files.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the primer problem. I know i shouldn't ask another question, however I also need to install the ssl package which is a builtin package. How could I include that one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ssl+macos

Comment: Thanks for your help, if you'd like you can post you suggestion as an answer and i'll accept it. As the packages: ['dns'... part solved my problem